# Extracting element from span with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the element that are circled in red in the picture below from this website:
https://eresearch.fidelity.com/eresearch/markets_sectors/sectors/sectors_in_market.jhtml?tab=learn&sector=25

[image]

However, it keeps giving me this error "ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?"

My idea is to narrow down the search to the "td" tag and use find to get the element from the "span" tag, but I just can't get it to work.  I tried using both find() and find_all() but both keep giving me this error, below is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://eresearch.fidelity.com/eresearch/markets_sectors/sectors/sectors_in_market.jhtml? 
tab=learn&sector=25"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'lxml')
b = soup.select('div.left-content table.snapshot-data-tbl tr td') 
print(b.find("span", class_='positive').text)
```

Can I please get some help on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`soup.select` returns a container with the matches from the provided CSS selector. The `soup.find` method can only be applied to an element node from the page source, not the set of results from `soup.select`. Instead, you can iterate over the results of `soup.select` to get the text from the target `span`s:

```
r = [i.get_text(strip=True) for i in soup.select('div.left-content table.snapshot-data-tbl tr td > span:nth-of-type(1)')[:3]]
```

Output:

```
['+0.62%', '$8.82T', '12.32%']
```

Comment: Hey there! Thank you so much for the help!  Can you explain what does this "> span:nth-of-type(1)')[:3]" mean?

Comment: @EricsonLi `> span:nth-of-type(1)` is an update on your original CSS selector, it searches for the very first `span` that is a child of a `td`. That way, you do not have to rely on specifying the `class` name `"positive"`, which not all of the target `span`s have. `[:3]` truncates the results so that only the first three are included.

Comment: Got it! Thank you so so so much for the help! Learned a lot from you :)

Comment: @EricsonLi Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

Typically it's cleaner to find the element by class or id if possible over the longer CSS selector. In this case the data you want is inside the table with class="*snapshot-data-tbl*" within the first 3 td elements.

Here's another solution to extract the values:

```python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://eresearch.fidelity.com/eresearch/markets_sectors/sectors/sectors_in_market.jhtml?tab=learn&sector=25"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
table = soup.find('table', class_="snapshot-data-tbl")
r = [td.find('span').text for td in table.find_all('td')[:3]]
print(r)
```

**Output:**

```
['+0.62%', '$8.82T', '12.32%']
```